# Calculating MIPS for multi-cycle vs single-cycle and getting weird answer

Tags: architecture, clock, processor, instructions, cpu-speed

I've got a problem where I need to calculate the MIPS for two systems, one single-cycle, and one multi-cycle. I don't think I'm doing the math right, and I was hoping someone would be kind enough to explain what I'm missing.

**Calculating GHz For my single cycle system...**

My understanding is that a single-cycle system can only run as fast as it's slowest instruction. It's slowest instruction takes 3.96 x 10^(-10) seconds to run. That means that it can run that instruction 1 / (3.96 x 10^(-10)) times per second, which comes out to 2.53 x 10^9 cycles per second, or 2.53 GHz.

**Calculating GHz For my multi cycle system...**

The mean speed of one of my multi-cycle instructions is 3.6862 x 10^(-10) seconds. That means it can run 1 / (3.682 x 10^(-10)) times per second, which comes out to 2.71 x 10^9 cycles per second, or 2.71 GHz.

...

Okay, so makes sense to me so far. A multi-cycle system is more efficient and therefore can run faster overall. But on this next part I'm getting a confusing answer.

**Calculating the MIPS rating of my single cycle system...**

Because it's a single cycle system, it automatically has 1 cycle / instr.

```
2.53 x 10^9 (cycles / sec) / 1 (cycle / instr) = 
2.53 x 10 ^ 9 (instr / sec) -> 
2.53 x 10 ^ 9 / 10^6 (MIPS) =  
2.53 x 10 ^ 3 (MIPS) = 
2,530 MIPS    <--- ??
```

Which seems like a lot. Especially when you consider my next answer.

**Calculating the MIPS rating of my multi cycle system...**

Mean # of cycles per instruction for my multi-cycle system: 4

```
2.71 x 10^9 (cycles / sec) / 4 (cycles / instr) = 
.6775 x 10^9 (instr / sec) -> 
.6775 x 10 ^ 9 / 10 ^ 6 (MIPS) = 
677.5 MIPS
```

**There's no way that my single-cycle system can calculate almost x4 as many MIPS as my multi-cycle system, right?**

Something has to be wrong with my calculations, or otherwise I misunderstand something fundamental about the way these systems work.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are your multi-cycle system Pipelined or not? If not, it is breaking every instruction into 4 pieces and each piece is executed in near speed like in single cycle. Then yes, your single cycle is faster. But if multicycle is pipelined, it can start instruction at every cycle, and your calculation should be changed. PS: Are your systems real or theoretic?

Comment: The systems are theoretic (based on a textbook problem) and the multi cycle is NOT pipelined. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I think, your single-cycled MIPS has too high frequency, this will be not possible (or very hard) to make so fast wide multipliers.